# Center aligning a switch in Horizontal Stack View

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Note: I'm completely new to iOS development.

In storyboard, I've got a Vertical Stack View with a Horizontal Stack View inside.

In the Horizontal Stack View, I've got a label and a switch. I changed the Distribution of both stack views to "Fill Equally".

[image]

[image]

[image]

Currently, this is what the view looks like:

[image]

The label is aligned perfectly both horizontally and vertically, but the switch is in the wrong position. I also want the switch to be aligned like the label, so that it appears on the right of the label and on the same vertical level.

I've tried various options with storyboard but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Set a background color to you label. You will see it has scaled to the height of the Vertical Stack View. UISwitch does *not* scale like that, so it draws at the top of a "forced" height change. Ignoring stack views for the moment, how do you *want* it to look?

Answer (score 7):

1. Set the alignment of the horizontal UIStackView to Center.
2. Embed the switch in a vertical UIStackView (inside the horizontal UIStackView).
3. Set the alignment of the new UIStackView to Center.

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question imho, no idea how horizontal content hugging could help.

Answer (score 6):

1. Set horizontal stackView alignment to center and distribution to
   fill.
2. Set the switch horizontal content hugging priority to required.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple.

your `horizontal stackView` will contain `UILabel` and `UIView`(let's call it `vSwitchContainer`).

Now place your switch inside `vSwitchContainer`. assign constraints for horizontally and vertically centre for `UISwitch`

Comment: Good Solution, but it looks more like a hack.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the switch itself, as the size changes, is always in the top left corner.  Create a view as a container, and put the switch inside that view, then set the horizontal and vertical constraints for the switch to be centered relative to that view (CTRL + drag from the switch to it's parent view, and select 'center horizontal

Comment: Bit formatting to your answer brings in magic. Do some formatting

Comment: I tried to do that, but now the UISwitch is not responding

Answer (score 0):

If you add a height constraint to the UILabel you will see that it will behave exactly the same as the UISwitch. The UILabel can fill the container while the switch has a "natural" height constraint.

- If you want to align both the view to the center and have more switch-label pairs one under the other, create a container view for each pair and put them directly in the first StackView or change the parent (vertical) StackView configuration (since there is where you issue actually is)
- If the expected result is other detail it in the question

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a vertical stack. Here's what I recommend as a tutorial / learning experience.

1. Start all over.
2. Create a view that is the area where you want the label and switch to be.  Make sure you have the constraints set. (Change the background color so that you can see it better.)
3. Within that view, put the label and switch.
4. Highlight the label and switch, and select the horizontal stackview.
5. Set the constraints of the horizontal stack to its superview (i.e., the view you created in step 2)
6. Configure the horizontal stackview until happy or come back to SO with a new question

Answer (score 0):

In Storyboard distribution will be set fill insted of fill equaly and add uiview in the stack view.Then set width for label and UISwitch.