# How do I horizontally center a UISwitch in a stack view?

Tags: ios, interface-builder

I'm using Interface Builder to create an application. I would like to have a set of labels and corresponding UISwitches arranged such that all labels appear on the left half of the screen, and the switches are on the right. The switches should be aligned with the labels.

To do this, I've tried using a vertical Stack View with multiple horizontal Stack Views embedded inside of it (one horizontal Stack View per label/switch pair). To get the labels and switches aligned correctly, I've set each of them inside a blank UIView and centered them (the switches and labels) on their appropriate UIView. Then the Stack Views are set to "Center" alignment and "Fill Equally" distribution.

With this setup I get the appropriate visual layout, but the UISwitches cannot be activated even though every parent view has "User Interaction Enabled" set. If I move the switch into the horizontal Stack View directly (without embedding it in a blank UIView) it works correctly, but I can't get it to center the way I want.

How can I have the layout I want and still have functional UISwitches?

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44591584/3377150), but none of the answers appear to solve my problem.

---

To reproduce:

1. Create a new View Controller
2. Add Vertical Stack View (VSV)
3. Set VSV's constraints to be equal height and equal width to the View Controller's root view, and center horizontally and vertically
4. Set VSV's alignment to "Center" and distribution to "Fill Equally"
5. Add 1+ Horizontal Stack Views (HSVs) to the VSV
6. Set each HSV to "Center" alignment and "Fill Equally" distribution
7. Add two blank UIViews to each HSV
8. For each HSV, constrain it to be of equal width to the VSV
9. For each HSV, add a UILabel to the first UIView and a UISwitch to the second UIView
10. For each UILabel and UISwitch, constrain it to be centered both horizontally and vertically on its parent UIView

When you run the application, the layout is perfect. However, none of the UISwitches can be interacted with, even though every successive parent view has user interaction enabled.

My hierarchy from Interface Builder: [image: IB Hierarchy]

The built application where switches don't work: [image: Test Application]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you can't interact with the switch is because the blank view that contains it ends up with a height of 0. Constrain that (blank) parent view's height so that it doesn't get resized to zero, or constrain the switch top and bottom to the parent (with a value of 0).

Comment: Another way to see this is to make the background of either view containing the UISwitch a different color.  In the storyboard it looks like the view is much bigger than the switch.  When you run the app, however, you see no colored background, the size of the containing view is being compressed.  Add a width and height constraint to the view and it will now show the background and the button will be now be selectable.

Comment: Since the container view is within a horizontal stack view, and is set to fill, a width constraint is not needed for it.

Comment: Adding a height constraint fixed it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Use the View Debugger when this things happen. You will be able to see which view is overlapping yours